# has_many association between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a rake task that allocates a score when comparing a prediction and result, at the moment the relationship is a has_one, as in a prediction has_one :result..

I want to change this to a prediction has_many :results. My task looks like this

```
namespace :grab do
 task :scores => :environment do
  Prediction.all.each do |prediction|
   score = points_total prediction, prediction.result
   allocate_points prediction, score
  end
 end
end

def points_total(prediction, result)
  wrong_predictions = [prediction.home_score - result.home_score, prediction.away_score - result.away_score]
  wrong_predictions = wrong_predictions.reject { |i| i == 0 }.size # returns 0, 1 or 2
   case wrong_predictions
    when 0 then 3
    when 1 then 1
    else 0
  end
 end

 def allocate_points(prediction, score)
  prediction.update_attributes!(score: score)
end
```

At the moment when running the task i get the error

```
undefined method result for Prediction Class
```

So with the has_many relationship would i be able to access the result attributes via

```
prediction.result.home_score
```

or am i getting confused somewhere. I dont know how to refactor my rake task to fit in with the new relationship

Any advice appreciated

EDIT

even after receiving the below advice from @andrunix cant seem to figure out how to apply to the rake task , this is what i have so far but get error undefined method to_i for array

```
namespace :grab do
 task :scores => :environment do
  Prediction.all.each do |prediction|
   score = points_total prediction
   allocate_points prediction, score
  end
 end
end

def points_total prediction
 prediction.results.each do |result|
  result_h = result.home_score
  result_a = result.away_score
  wrong_predictions = [prediction.home_score - result_h, prediction.away_score - result_a]
  wrong_predictions = wrong_predictions.reject { |i| i == 0 }.size # returns 0, 1 or 2
  case wrong_predictions
  when 0 then 3
  when 1 then 1
  else 0
  end
 end
end

 def allocate_points prediction, score
  prediction.update_attributes!(score: score)
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

If a prediction :has_many results, then results is now a collection and you'll have to treat it as such. You can't say,

```
prediction.result.home_score
```

You have to reference results with an array index like,

```
prediction.results[0].home_score
```

Or iterate over the collection of results like:

```
prediction.results.each do |result|
    result.home_score # do something with the score
end
```

I realize this doesn't totally answer the "how to refactor" question but if a Prediction :has_many results, you can't simply reference prediction.result anymore.

Hope that helps.

Comment: no that does help, thank you, i just needed some clarification

Comment: have taken your advice and tried to implement based on understanding but having issue with undefined method to_i for array..would you know how to get around this?

Comment: which part do you want to see?, i have updated my question with my current logic, see edit

Comment: Is the 'score' variable an array?

Comment: well score is an attribute in my prediction model set as an integer, i dont think the variable score is an array

Comment: ok so if i add puts score.inspect under  score = points_total prediction and run the rake task the output is =>Result id: 8, home_team: \"Stoke\", away_team: \"Tottenham\", home_score: 1, away_score: 2, fixture_date: \"2013-05-12\", prediction_id: 18, created_at: \"2013-05-15 15:09:52\", updated_at: \"2013-05-15 15:09:52\">]...still get error though